# Detecting HTTP request errors

Tags: python, http, cgi

I have a problem with the request and I need to know more about the problem . I tried the following prints but still I need to know what are the exact parameters sent by request that cause this error .

```
response = requests.post(urls[my_form], data = final_form)
       
          print(response.status_code)
          print(response.reason)
          print(response.text)

        if response and response.ok:
            db.write_content(my_form, response.text, table)
```

Comment: Only the server knows. **If** it sends that information back it will be in the response text.

Comment: yes it'a an internal server error but I do not know what/where is it exactly

Comment: Internal server errors (error codes 5xx) are errors of the server. Often bad exception or data handling. In production they shouldn't inform the client of details. If anywhere you will find details about the problem in the server log.

Comment: Thank you . I found this in server log  
client denied by server configuration: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/.DS_Store, referer: http://localhost:8888/MAMP/?language=English
any suggestion ?